# ASP.NET Order bool with not set

Tags: c#, linq, boolean

How do I order a bool by null first, then true, then false

```
return View("Index", db.HolidayRequestForms.ToList().OrderByDescending(e => e.Approved).ThenBy(e => e.RequestID))
```

I am using a using a custom display template for the bool, I don't know if that matters

Comment: `not set` - do you mean `Approved` is nullable?

Comment: @Alex Yes, this is for a request page so nullable would be pending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom comparer

```
public class ApprovedComparer : IComparer<bool?>
{
    public int Compare(bool? x, bool? y)
    {
        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;

        if (x.HasValue)
            a = x.Value ? 1 : 2;
        if (y.HasValue)
            b = y.Value ? 1 : 2;

        return a - b;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
return View("Index", db.HolidayRequestForms.ToList()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Approved, new ApprovedComparer())
    .ThenBy(e => e.RequestID))
```

Can be tested in LinqPad (or a normal console app)

```
public class Thing
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool? Approved { get; set; }
}

public class ApprovedComparer : IComparer<bool?>
{
    public int Compare(bool? x, bool? y)
    {
        var a = 0;
        var b = 0;

        if (x.HasValue)
            a = x.Value ? 1 : 2;
        if (y.HasValue)
            b = y.Value ? 1 : 2;

        return a - b;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var thing1 = new Thing { Approved = null, Name = "Thing 1" };
    var thing2 = new Thing { Approved = true, Name = "Thing 2", };
    var thing3 = new Thing { Approved = false, Name = "Thing 3" };

    //note the 'incorrect' order
    var listOfThings = new[] { thing3, thing2, thing1 };

    listOfThings
        .OrderBy(x => x.Approved, new ApprovedComparer())
        .Select(x => x.Name) //just for outputting the names
        .Dump(); //LinqPad specifc
}
```

**Output**

[image]

As of .net 4.5, you can use `Comparer<T>.Create()` to create a static comparer, which can be 'inline' - ie, no separate class required.

Personally, I find the separate class a bit cleaner to read. Just my opinion, however.

```
var comparer = Comparer<bool?>.Create((x, y) =>
   {
       var a = 0;
       var b = 0;

       if (x.HasValue)
           a = x.Value ? 1 : 2;
       if (y.HasValue)
           b = y.Value ? 1 : 2;

       return a - b;
   });

listOfThings
    .OrderBy(x => x.Approved, comparer)
    .Select(x => x.Name) //just for outputting the names
    .Dump(); //LinqPad specifc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
myList.OrderBy(v => !v)
```